# Is it safe to use $_ prefix on custom PHP variables

Tags: php, variables

I know it's possible to set custom PHP variables using the $_ prefix, however I am unsure if it is safe to do this? I wouldn't be setting many, nor would I be overwriting pre-set variables like $_SERVER or $_COOKIE. Should I just avoid doing it at all?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to set variables this way?

Comment: What's unsafe for you about that? You can name your variable the way you want, within the lexical rules

Comment: Yeah its fine, vars such as `$_COOKIE` are case sensitive

Comment: @Killrawr variables in PHP are case sensitive.  Functions and class names are not

Comment: @Killrawr all variables are casesensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely safe to initialize variables that start with `$_` as long as you don't override any of the superglobals (that you need).

However, the `$_` prefix on variables indicates that they are superglobals or have some other kind of magic behavior, so to do so on "normal" variables would be nonstandard.

Comment: It's actually quite common to denote non-public class properties with leading underscores (in many languages, including PHP).

Comment: @drrcknlsn class members are not accessed via `$_`

Comment: `However, the $_ prefix on variables indicates that they are superglobals or have some other kind of magic behavior` <-- Where did you read that? Look at either at ZF1 or ZF2, they indicate `$_var`class properties (objects in general) this way.

Comment: @ExplosionPills:  I didn't say that's how they are accessed.  It's just a very common naming practice, because it makes it easy to determine at a glance whether a property is public or not.  It's a part of quite a few coding standards, and definitely not bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

This notation is normally used inside classes to indicate private or protected members (either  properties or methods). In this situation it is completely safe.

Note, the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) has a caution on using double underscore to prefix methods, as this notation is reserved for "magic" methods. This caution does not apply to the single underscore prefix.